# SonarQube scan across multiple branches

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

Scenario: 3 branches in a repository:

'master' -> 'prod' branch which gets pushed to production

'devBranch A' - a development branch - assume single developer

'devBranch B' - a dev branch, same as above.

We have SonarQube (6.x) for static code analysis in a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline kicked off by the creation of a pull request in BitBucket. We use Git Jenkins plugin. Right now, Git is, upon creation of a pull request, doing a checkout from BitBucket as such:

```
Checking out Revision cdd7cc6fa787d111bbc6afef2728fa3353aab499 (origin/feature/TestTuesday)
```

I am trying to ensure that *only* the code from the specific pull request in that specific branch - and not all commits in any branch matching the pattern "origin/feature/*" is analysed by SonarQube - trying to ensure we never get *every* commit in all branches that match our Git Jenkins plugin 'branch specifier'

So how do I: ensure SonarQube scans only the code in a specific pull request as opposed to all changes in branches that match the branch specifier pattern.

thanks

EDIT: I was tempted to delete this question as I don't feel I've articulated this issue I'm trying to solve in a way that is actually technically relevant...

When the Jenkins/Git plugin checks out that code, it is actually checking out the correct code - that Revision is the Head commit in the repo from which the PR originated... so... this is doing what is expected.

Previously, another issue had been the correct paths to the source code for sonarqube analysis: they needed to be relative to the workspace for the Jenkins job...

Summary: instead of deleting this question, I'm just clarifying my poor wording and giving a brief follow up for anyone who may find any of this edifying.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take a look to the git hooks. Probably you can write a hook to check your code in Sonar before it will be pushed to repository. Additionally you can use plugin in your IDE like *SonarLint* which can be used to analyze code on the fly in IDE according your rules in Sonar, but hook will be more strictly comparing to plugin.

Comment: We are using SonarLint - these use cases model other scenarios - in the CI/CD pipeline, out of pipeline scans, etc... the IDE plugin, while of value, serves only one specific purpose, of course. As for the pre-scan hook of some kind... I imagine that is workable but I don't sense it as ideal and would like alternatives. I think honing the config of the git command that does the checkout is preferred...

Answer (score 0):

Considering you know which branch to pull, you can do

```
$ git fetch
$ git diff <branch>...origin/<branch>.
```

This will give you only the commits which will be pulled.
Note down the list of changes and pass it to sonar-scanner (or any other client you are using) to include only the files mentioned.

Something like this :

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.inclusions=<Comma-delimited list of files>
```

Now, since you are using a plugin to pull from git, what I suggest is, before the pull starts, do a git log and get old commit SHA, do a git pull, get new commit SHA. Using old and new SHAs, do a git diff/git log to fetch the list of files which have changes.

Comment: doesn't strike me as elegant, but I appreciate it nonetheless. I'll keep searching for what I feel is a more optimal solution.